# How should a chain of proof be written?

Tags: proof-writing, np-complete, article-writing

I have a to prove problem $P_{2}$ is NP-Complete. But for that I need to prove another intermediate problem $P_{1}$ NP-complete too. To prove $P_{1}$ I need to state that problem $P_{0}$ is already proven to be NP-complete. Now how should I arrange things while writing ?

> Lemma 1: Problem $P_{2}$ is NP-complete (with full definition of $P_{2}$)
>   Begin Proof: 
>  
>   Lemma 2: Problem $P_{1}$ is NP-complete (with full definition of $P_{1}$)
>  
>     Begin Proof 
>   Definition $P_{0}$ is known to be NP-complete 
>   ...
>   End Proof 
>   End proof

or should I first define all these problems

> State following defines our problem and how Definition 2 and 3 relates
>   Definition 1: $P_{2}$
>   Definition 2: $P_{1}$
>   Definition 3: $P_{0}$
>   State the sequence of the proof as follows
>   Lemma 1: Problem $P_{1}$ is NP-complete
>   Begin Proof
>   Refer $P_{0}$
>   $\dots$
>   End proof
>   Lemma 2: Problem $P_{2}$ is NP-complete
>   Begin proof
>   $\dots$
>   End Proof

Or I should use Lemma for all my problems

> State the sequence of the proof as follows (referred with acronyms)
>   Lemma 1(Problem Acronym): Problem $P_{1}$ is NP-complete (with full definition of $P_{1}$)
>   Begin Proof
>   Definition 3: $P_{0}$
>   Refer $P_{0}$
>   $\dots$
>   End proof
>   Lemma 2(Problem Acronym): Problem $P_{2}$ is NP-complete (with full definition of $P_{2}$)
>   Begin proof
>   $\dots$
>   End Proof

In my case definitions are not small, it takes 8 lines of one column in 2 column paper. What style of writing is easier to follow ?